# Issue in wild card

Tags: php, wildcard

I have 2 wild cards

1. "PersonalBlue M.*Mat"
2. "PersonalBlue M.*Copay.*Mat"

and both pattern are match with string "PersonalBlue M14P $3,500/80%; $35 Copay 4 Visits; 50% Rx w/Mat"

```
<?php

eregi('PersonalBlue M.*Mat', 'PersonalBlue M14P $3,500/80%; $35 Copay 4 Visits; 50% Rx w/Mat', $matches);

eregi('PersonalBlue M.*Copay.*Mat', 'PersonalBlue M14P $3,500/80%; $35 Copay 4 Visits; 50% Rx w/Mat', $matches2);

echo "<br>";
echo strlen ($matches[0]);
echo "<br>";
echo strlen ($matches2[0]);

?>
```

The length of matched string is same for both. I need the first wild card should match with the string "PersonalBlue M09P $2,500/80%; 50% Rx w/Mat" but not with the "PersonalBlue M14P $3,500/80%; $35 Copay 4 Visits; 50% Rx w/Mat".

What will be the appropriate first wild card?

Comment: eregi O_O doesn't they spam a lot of DEPRECATED there ? XD

Comment: @yes123: Only if you don't have a broken dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following correctly, you want `'PersonalBlue M14P $3,500/80%; $35 Copay 4 Visits; 50% Rx w/Mat'` to only match `'PersonalBlue M.*Copay.*Mat'` and not match something along the lines of `'PersonalBlue M.*Mat'`.

If `'PersonalBlue M.*Mat'` is changed to `'PersonalBlue M.*(^Copay).*Mat'` it will not match if Copay is in between `PersonalBlue M` and `Mat`.

```
<?php

eregi('PersonalBlue M.*(^Copay).*Mat', 'PersonalBlue M14P $3,500/80%; $35 Copay 4 Visits; 50% Rx w/Mat', $matches);

eregi('PersonalBlue M.*Copay.*Mat', 'PersonalBlue M14P $3,500/80%; $35 Copay 4 Visits; 50% Rx w/Mat', $matches2);

echo "<br>";
echo strlen ($matches[0]); // outputs 0
echo "<br>";
echo strlen ($matches2[0]); // outputs 62

?>
```

As @yes123 pointed out, `eregi` has been deprecated and you might want to look at preg_match instead.

Comment: i use that pattern. 'PersonalBlue M.*(^Copay).*Mat' doesn't match with string 'PersonalBlue M14P $3,500/80%; $35 Copay 4 Visits; 50% Rx w/Mat' and 'PersonalBlue M09P $2,500/80%; 50% Rx w/Mat' too. i want that pattern should match with 'PersonalBlue M09P $2,500/80%; 50% Rx w/Mat'

Comment: Yup, you are totally correct. Sorry, I did not read the question properly and mainly went off your code example. I haven't had as good of luck coming up with an answer to the second part though. Question though, your target string is always semicolon delimited, could you do a split or do you have to use a regex?